# Do I need to configure Authorities in ManifoldCF?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, document-management, manifoldcf

On Apache ManifoldCF I have configured a CMIS Repository Connector which accesses only one document repository. During the configuration phase, I provided the administrator user and password. I use this CMIS Repository Connector in two Jobs connected respectively to a MongoDB Output Connector and an Elasticsearch Output Connector.
Do I need to configure Authorities?